# Connecting four 2.5" external USB HDDs with a 48 watts powered USB Hub

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3, usb-hub, portable-harddrive

Need to access four USB HDDs simultaneously while having only one available USB3 Type A port in laptop...

Found a 10 port 48 watts hub "Orico AT2U3-10AB" where I thought of keeping 6 ports always off with their individual on/off switches and use remaining 4 ports for four 2.5" WD My Passport 2TB USB HDDs... https://www.orico.cc/usmobile/product/detail/id/7177.html

48 watts total power will be 43 watts after approximate conversion loss... I'm assuming this 43 watts will get evenly distributed to the 4 ports at 10.75 watts per port, which should mean 5V/2.15A... Do these Hubs actually work like this? Can they provide stable enough power/current to four HDDs simultaneously without damaging them?

If USB Hubs will not work, what are my options since I can't connect them directly to any sort of docking station, as removing their USB interfaced enclosures will violate warranty...

Answer (score 1):

Without a model number for the HDDs and the hub, its not possible to be accurate.  Gothcas - from my experience

1. USB Hubs capacity rating is the total for all ports.  If you use only two ports out of four, you dont get the 30W (unless specified otherwise)
2. USB Hard disks consume a large amount of power.  If the hub can not keep up (for instance when both drives are demanding power), the voltage can drop and your disks could get damaged.

I realised all this after destroying a few disks and a few motherboards and a hub.  Now I power one HDD from the motherboard and the other from the hub.  Everything has been working fine for the last year.

Comment: Do you have more details on the failures? In the USB hubs i've opened the v+ and Ground lines are common. All 2.5" HDDs I'm aware of use much less then 10 watts on startup, and those include internal 7200 RPM drives.

Comment: I would concede plugging an internal 2.5 inch disk using an enclosure on a USB2 port could draw more then 500ma and damage the port if plugged in directly - but thats witjhout a powered hub.

Comment: Hello Rohit, the two HDDs are Western Digital My Passport 2tbs and the hub is Orico AT2U3-10AB... This hub has individual on/off switches for each port, so I was thinking I'll keep only 3 ports on when using two for the HDDs and one for the mouse...

Comment: @eebtesherahmed Orico make "reasonable" equipment - ie its Chinese stuff, but its not cheapest bidder chinese junk and is sold by large,reputable computer stores (at least in NZ)   It should perform fine.  Per https://www.orico.cc/us/product/detail/7177.html it supports multiple HDD's - it only promises 1.5 amps per port, but that is adequate.

Comment: @davidgo This Orico hub has individual on/off switches for each port and is powered by a 48 watts source... So assuming 2 watts taken by the circuits, hub itself, LEDs and system loss, will the remaining 46 watts be equally available for each of the 10 ports at 4.6 watts (0.92A) each? And if I keep 6 ports always switched off, does this mean more power (46w/4) = 11.5 watts (2.3A) will be available for each of the 4 ports that'll be on?... (Don't know how it promises 1.5A per port, as than total power requirement goes to 5V*1.5A*10= 75 watts whereas power adapter providing 12V*4A= 48 watts)

Comment: eebtesher ahmed, you added important facts in your comments. Please include them into your initial question! Thank you.

Comment: @r2d3 Okay I'm updating my initial question with more details... Should I delete the other later question I posted starting the new thread?... I joined this group recently and am a bit confused on how to reply to a particular answer instead of making a general comment...

Comment: @davidgo How did you understand that this hub supports multiple HDDs? Though I would be very happy if it does, and won't wait to buy it tomorrow even with it's high price tag of $46...

Comment: Look under your link for the section "External Power Supply".  It says "It supports 4TB capacity hard drive and **multiple devices connection**"  (Emphasis mine, I think I have above average Chinglish interpretation skills! )

Comment: @davidgo Bought it and using it for last 3 days with just a mouse and one HDD for the time being... Not finding issues yet, have copied files and read files with USB 3.0 regular speeds obviously, as no other simultaneous read/writes going on... Will try a second HDD after a while...

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine.

USB 2 guarantees 500ma (2.5w) and USB 3 guarantees 900ma - less than 5 watts - so 30 watts is way more than required.

There are always data corruption risks (regardless of disk or interface - what happens if there is a power failure), but a journalling filesystem should mitigate this.

Comment: David, in terms of power needed you are right, there will be no noticeable drop in Volts probably, but with a fixed output voltage of 5V for HDDs there is no guarantee for unlimited current for an individual slot. Raising the output power given a fixed 5V output requires going beyond the 900mA barrier.

Comment: @R2D3 I don't disagree - except to point out 2.5" USB hdd's are designed to be powered by USB.

Comment: Maybe! I avoid 2,5'' USB drives now. I rather buy the enclosure and put in a disk of my choice. When in need of data recovery having a striped down 2,5'' disk without SATA access is something I'd like to avoid. I prefeer steel disks put into a steel housing instead of running a plastic housing that prevent thermal flow.

Answer (score 1):

## Power requirements of USB-devices

2,5'' HDDs exhibit current spikes that can easily go beyond the specified current of 900mA during startup and to a lesser degree on read and write operations later on. As your linked Orico datasheet states that the current limit is 900mA for the VL817 chip used in your device, you max experience problems during startup or later. Startup problems may be detected by hearing the drive restarting again and again. Switch off power in that particular case.

On the other hands there are powered USB-Hubs, notebooks and mainboards that allow for higher currents knowing that 2,5'' HDDs might not start otherwise.

Nobody can give you a performance guarantee as 2,5'' disks vary in terms of their startup current needs.

Therefore **you would need to test that out with disks whose data you can afford to loose**.

Switching on high current power consumers one by one could mitigate the problem.

After experiencing startup problems with 9mm 2,5'' disks I measured their current needs at startup. Depending on manufacturer and setting startup current varied from 600mA to 1100mA? (do not find my logging protocol for the 1100 mA case).

## comment on your ORICO-AT2U3-10AB USB-Hub

Chip manufacturer Via Labs praises its "optimized cost-structure" which makes my eyebrow raise.

The Orico spec sheet defies the laws of physics stating that **each port provides 1,5A for prolonged using.**

That gives a power requirements of 5V * 1,5A = 7,5W per slot.
Using 10 ports simultaneously requires 10 * 7,5W = 75 W but the power supply only offers 12V * 4A = 48W which does not take into account a conversion loss of say 10%. Turning approx 48W * (1-10%) =~43W after conversion to 5V into 75W (output requirement) qualifies the brave Orico (marketing) engineers for the Nobel prize.

Very often externally powered hubs come with insufficient power supplies that do not match the output power capabilities of the related USB-Hub.

The quoted 1,5A = 1500 mA only seems to apply to BC (battery charge) mode.

Comment: That is why I was asking if I can keep 6 ports switched off all the time to get the 48 watts for the 4 ports... Does it work like this? If yes, than I would get 12 (5V*2.4A) watts in each port... (That is, if we can believe the 12V*4A=48 rating on the power supply and for simplicity ignore the Hub circuits/LEDs' power consumptions)

Comment: No. You did not get my point, higher input power does not increase the ability of the 5V output to deliver more current. You won't get 48 W / 5A = 9,6 A when running just one drive. The only thing that will happen is that the voltage drop will be very low - can't give you an exact estimation. The output current is certainly limited by either the chip or the switching power circuitry if there are individual circuits to step 12V down to 5V.

Comment: If one of your attached USB devices exceeds a certain current for a certain time the VL817 chip inside the hub has to assume that the USB device is faulty - drawing current beyond any reasonable means and will shut down the affected port. Please search the pdf-spec sheet for "USBOC1  25  I 
DFP1 USB OC 
USB Over Current Detection 
    High: Normal 
    Low: Port Over Current Event "

Comment: If the datasheet claims 1.5A "prolonged" current, then we can assume that's the maximum... So these HDDs should be good if we could confirm that 1.5A will be stable or will be available on demand on these four ports... So unless someone is actually using hubs/HDDs this way, we can't be sure... 

Comment: This Hub model claims it supports 4TB HDD and multiple devices connection... I'm guessing if it supported multiple HDDs, it would've claimed so... So it doesn't work 

Comment: Your disk does not operate in BC (battery charge) mode what I already wrote above.

Comment: Bought the hub and using it for last 3 days with just a mouse and one HDD for the time being... Not finding issues yet, have copied files and read files with USB 3.0 regular speeds obviously, as no other simultaneous read/writes going on... Will try a second HDD after a while...